# Conversion error when inserting value from user textbox

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table on a database server

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[io] (
 [io_id] INT NOT NULL, 
 [name] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
 [gender] CHAR (10) NULL,
 [rank] VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
 [salary] INT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([io_id] ASC) );
```

To this table I am inserting data using following code:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::CFMSApp.Properties.Settings.Default.CFMSConnectionString);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into io values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("adding new record done");
        textBox1.Text = " ";
        textBox2.Text = " ";
        textBox3.Text = " ";
        textBox4.Text = " ";
        textBox5.Text = " ";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error");
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error when inserting a record:

> Conversion failed when converting varchar value 'anagha' to datatype int

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: how many columns does `io` have and what is the data type for each column?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Google for `Bobby Tables`. *DON'T* use string concatenation to create queries. Use parameterized queries

Comment: Don't ever build a SQL statement from user input. Use parametrized queries.

Comment: io has 5 columns and textbox1 refers to varchar type

Comment: i'm getting error as "conversion failed when converting varchar value 'anagha' to datatype int

Comment: it means one or more of your columns is not char/varchar, textbox1 maybe is varchar, but what about the rest?  Show us the full table info.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[io] (
    [io_id]  INT          NOT NULL,
    [name]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [gender] CHAR (10)    NULL,
    [rank]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [salary] INT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([io_id] ASC)
);

Comment: your first column, io_id, is an int, why are you inserting a string?

Comment: 1) switch to a parameterized query 2) rename your text boxes so that the field they map to is clear.

Answer (score 0):

your query string has an error put it like this

> insert into io (io_id,name,gender,rank,salary)
>   values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";

on what your doing your textbox1.text which is 'anagha' is inputting on the io_id and that is on integer value. your inputting a string on an integer that causes the problem.

i little bit of advice use parametized query. sql injection or hacking can be use on your program

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the first column? It's an INT. What is the type of textBox1.Text? It's a string. You can't implicitly convert a string to an INT.

Given that you have five values and five textboxes, but the first one obviously contains a string (i.e. "anagha"), it's hard to tell you how to fix the problem. Should textBox1 contain the value for io_id? If so, then perhaps io_id should be a varchar rather than an INT. On the other hand, if it must be an INT then you should prevent the user from entering characters in textBox1. Perhaps io_id should be auto-generated, in which case your table structure is wrong and you shouldn't have a field on the form for it at all. The poor naming conventions (i.e. textBox1, textBox2, etc) make it impossible to determine what your intent is.

However, one thing you absolutely should fix is the horribly SQL Injection problem you have.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into io values(@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4, @value5)";
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@value1", SqlDbType.Int)
{ Value = textBox1.Text };
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@value2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
{ Value = textBox2.Text };
// ... etc ...
```